# pysvnをmayaで使いたい

Tags: python

pysvn(py27-pysvn-svn1816-1.9.3-1884-Win64.exe(64bit版)をインストールしました。
コマンドラインからのpython(C:\Python27\python.exe)はimport pysvnで上手くいくのですが、
Maya2016からimport pysvnをすると次のエラーが出ます。

```
import pysvn

# Error: Error in  maya.utils._guiExceptHook:
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\utils.py", line 318, in formatGuiException
#     exceptionMsg = unicode(exceptionObject.args[0])
# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
# 
# Original exception was:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
#   File "C:/Users/~~~/Documents/maya/2016/scripts\pysvn\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
#     import _pysvn_2_7
# ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。 #
```

ネットで検索してみて、VisualStudio2017をインストールしてみたりしたのですが、
エラーメッセージは変化ありませんでした。

環境は
windows10, 64bit
maya2016です。(mayaの2015と2017でも試してみましたがダメでした。)

このサイトも見てみたのですが(https://dftalk.jp/?p=7224)、やり方がわからず。。

ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あなたはこれをやってみましたか？ `import sys, pysvn`

Comment: はい。sysもpysvnもimportしています。
import pysvn　の時点でエラーメッセージが表示されます。
python.exeでimportした時は問題なく動き、mayaというソフトでimportするとエラーになります。

Comment: あなたはそれらのために動作するかどうかを確認するために他のPythonモジュールをインポートしようとしましたか？

Comment: @Tatsuya Nakamori さん、編集履歴を見ました。せっかく英語に翻訳したなら、英語版のStack Overflowにも投稿してみてはどうでしょうか(日本語版で回答が得られなければ)？

Comment: @Aric Fowler
他のモジュールはすべてうまくいきます。
pysvnのみ上手くいきません。

Comment: @Kohei TAMURA
英語版と日本語版で違うんですね。初めての投稿で知りませんでした。(英語圏の方が英語で検索すれば引っかかるのかと思っておりました。。)

しばらくして解決しなかった場合は英語版に投稿してみようと思います。